# Error command test shell linux

Tags: shell-script, shell

Hello I have an error in this code. I want to check if file is readable and writable and check if this file contains the string "/usr/bin/python2", but the shell prints this error:

> grep /usr/bin/python2

How can I solve this?

```
if test -f $i -a test -w $i -a `grep /usr/bin/python2 < $i`
then
   echo $i
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if test -r "$i" -a -w "$i" && grep -q "/usr/bin/python2" "$i"
then
   echo "$i"
fi
```

You could also avoid the whole if statement and check for readability is done by grep implicitly:

```
test -w "$i" && grep -l "/usr/bin/python2" "$i" 2>/dev/null
```